# horizontal scrolling section in PagePiling.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pagepiling.js

I am trying to make a page which which have only two section 1st section which is at top have[image]  please see the image . Now I m able to go to div 1 to div 2 easily using pagePiling.js. can anyone tell me how to achieve the horizontal effect in div 1 . and after the end of the content on div 1 it must pagePile to div 2 . and when coming back to div 1 it user also see the effect of horizontal scroll.

Comment: pagePiling.js doesn't provide such option. You can go for [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) is you want to have both directions.

Comment: I need a scrollbale content on the first section/div and the section/ div will have horizontal scroll. All I need is when Horizontal scroll end the div below it with vertical scroll should appear with animation. and without showing the scrollbar

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to have a section with large content and therefore create an scroll bar for that section, you can do it by adding the class pp-scrollable to that section: